# プロトコルの準拠について

Tags: swift, swift3

```
func methodA<T:ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral>(n:T)->(){

    var i = 1
    var j = T(integerLiteral:i) 
}
```

上記の関数は、「var j = T(integerLiteral:i) 」でコンパイルエラーとなります。

しかし、私の解釈では、T型は、ExpressibleByIntegerLiteralプロトコルに準拠しているとしており、またプロトコルは、init(integerLiteral:)[REQUIRED]とあるので、なぜエラーとなるのかが理解ができません。
私は何が理解できていないのでしょうか。教えてください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

私も一瞬、「なんでこれがダメなんだろう?」と思ってしまった側なんですが…。

まずはプロトコル`ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`の定義を再確認してみましょう。

> ```
> /// Conforming types can be initialized with integer literals.
> public protocol ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
>
>     associatedtype IntegerLiteralType
>
>     /// Create an instance initialized to `value`.
>     public init(integerLiteral value: Self.IntegerLiteralType)
> }
> ```

`init(integerLiteral:)`メソッド(イニシャライザ)のパラメータ型は`Int`ではなく、`Self.IntegerLiteralType`になっています。あなたが`T: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`以外の何の制約も与えず`func methodA<T:ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral>(n:T)->()`でメソッド宣言をした場合、`T.IntegerLiteralType`は`Int`しかないと決定付けることはできず、メソッド本体は(今は定義されていなくとも、可能性としてありえる)任意の`T.IntegerLiteralType`について動作するように記述しないといけません。

よって、`var i = 1`で`Int`型と決定されてしまった`i`を引数にして`init(integerLiteral:)`を呼ぶことはできない、と言うことになってエラーが発生しているわけです。

したがって、これは構文エラーにはなりません。

```
func methodA<T: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral>(n: T) -> ()
    where T.IntegerLiteralType == Int
{
    var i = 1
    var j = T(integerLiteral: i)
    //...
}
```

あるいは、こんな書き方をすることもできます。

```
func methodA<T: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral>(n: T) -> () {
    var j: T = 1
    //...
}
```

何となく雰囲気くらいはつかんでいただけたでしょうか。ジェネリックを使った宣言は、「制約を満たすどんなデータ型が来ても動くように書かないとエラーになってしまう」と言うことを頭に叩き込んだ上で、プロトコルの定義などを見直せば、より理解が深まるかと思います。

Comment: Tの型が何かの型に決定した時、init(integerLiteral:Int)が実装されている保証はないのでエラーとなる。ですね。


私は、ExpressibleByIntegerLiteralプロトコルに適合しているので、Tはinit(integerLiteral:)イニシャライザは実装されている。そして「i」は、Int型なので、init(integerLiteral:Int)になるので使用できると思い込んでいましたが、

現実的に、TがInt8だった場合、そのようなイニシャライザは無いので、ダメですね。

理解ができたとは言えませんが、なにかつかめてきました感じがします。
回答していただいた内容を何回も見直そうと思います。
ありがとうございました。